# Message from webpage

Tags: email

Message from wepage popups in my yahoo email account. I need to x the box several times to unfreeze my computer. Then, it keeps popping up. And this occcurs before I even open any mail. exact message: "message from webp, then hi, then 40401508, then 1"

Any suggestion to get ride of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run any anti-virus or anti-malware utility of your choosing on your computer. Follow any instructions that it provides on how to clean and remove whatever cruft is causing this. There are lots of free versions available online, but you should consider purchasing a subscription to a well-regarded utility from a reputable company. These days, browsing the Internet without protection is just asking for trouble!

If that doesn't work, the next step is backing up your important data, erasing your computer's disk, and re-installing your operating system from scratch. It sounds drastic, but it's really not all that bad. Plus, it will fix any other problems you've been having and probably speed up your machine noticeably.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much Cody. Appreciate your time.